# Android countdown timer from TextView

Tags: android, datetime, timer

Is it possible for a countdown timer that would make a count from this time and to the `dateTime` that is stated from the `textview` the format of the datetime is `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM`.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes use java **Date** and add a timer / **Thread** with a count of **60 second** (60,000) as in your case the lowest is :MM and set Text to the Text view for every 60 second interval passed. First you will need to get the system time then instead of using a textView (User can view only) use EditText (User can edit/input/view) get the value and compare them for count down.